# what is a difference between resource and source in programming

Tags: python-3.x

I had a question for separating my python project files.
What is a difference between "resource" and "source" in programming?
When I should use "resource" separation and When I must use "source"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source generally means program code in a compilable and human-readable language (as opposed to the target code being the binary code ultimately executed by the processor).

A resource is typically data included in the executable image. Think error messages, pictures, sound clips, icons and such.